# Parsec parser failed on many1 and manyTill combinators

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have faced with an unclear behavior of parsec parsers, so I want to parsre strings as same

```
>  <CdId>
1

>  <Mol Weight>
270.2369

>  <Formula>
C15H10O5

>  <LOG_ER_RBA>
-0.36

>  <ACTIVITY>
1
```

I wrote a parser

```
 parseProperties = do       
        skipMany1 newline
        char '>' >> spaces >> char '<' 
        propName <- many1 (noneOf ">")
        char '>'
        newline
        propValue <- many1 (noneOf "\n")
        return (propName,propValue)
```

This parser excellently parse one item, and also is able to parse several:

```
parseTest (count 5 parseProperties) "\n>  <CdId>\n1\n\n>  <Mol Weight>\n270.2369\n\n>  <Formula>\nC15H10O5\n\n>  <LOG_ER_RBA>\n-0.36\n\n>  <ACTIVITY>\n1\n\n"
```

results

```
 [("CdId","1"),("Mol Weight","270.2369"),("Formula","C15H10O5"),("LOG_ER_RBA","-0.36"),("ACTIVITY","1")]
```

---

Nevertheless I found no ways to parse random numbers of properties. If I try

```
parseTest (many1 parseProperties) "\n>  <CdId>\n1\n\n>  <Mol Weight>\n270.2369\n\n>  <Formula>\nC15H10O5\n\n>  <LOG_ER_RBA>\n-0.36\n\n>  <ACTIVITY>\n1\n\n"
```

or

```
parseTest (manyTill parseProperties (try eof)) "\n>  <CdId>\n1\n\n>  <Mol Weight>\n270.2369\n\n>  <Formula>\nC15H10O5\n\n>  <LOG_ER_RBA>\n-0.36\n\n>  <ACTIVITY>\n1\n\n"
```

parser failed

```
parse error at (line 17, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting new-line or ">"
```

But, if I use anyChar parser, it is not failed.

```
parseTest (manyTill anyChar (try eof)) "\n>  <CdId>\n1\n\n>  <Mol Weight>\n270.2369\n\n>  <Formula>\nC15H10O5\n\n>  <LOG_ER_RBA>\n-0.36\n\n>  <ACTIVITY>\n1\n\n"

"\n>  <CdId>\n1\n\n>  <Mol Weight>\n270.2369\n\n>  <Formula>\nC15H10O5\n\n>  <LOG_ER_RBA>\n-0.36\n\n>  <ACTIVITY>\n1\n\n"
```

Comment: Can I advise that `many1 (noneOf ">")` is bad practice. Use `noneOf` sparingly - it's much better to decide what _is_ allowed instead of what isn't. You've said that a `propertyName` is anything that's not a `>`. That allows a property called `%^$  \t  5&/\n\n<tag start 3564 % ^  & * % "`. Similarly `propValue` can be absolutely anything that's not a newline. Instead, specify the things is can be, and parse them. It's more effort, but the job of a parser is to get the _right_ data and reject incorrect data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parseProperties` parser is executed many times in your example until
`eof` is encountered. The problem is that `parseProperties` does not consume
the trailing whitespace in your example, so after parsing the last tag, the
remaining string is `"\n\n"`, which will not trigger your termination
condition, since it is not the end of input. This causes the `parseProperties`
to be attempted again, which consumes the whitespace but fails when trying to
eat a `'>'`.

Try modifying your `parseTest` to the following

```
test = "\n>  <CdId>\n1\n\n>  <Mol Weight>\n270.2369\n\n>  <Formula>\nC15H10O5\n\n>  <LOG_ER_RBA>\n-0.36\n\n>  <ACTIVITY>\n1\n\n"

parseTest (manyTill parseProperties $ try (skipMany newline >> eof)) test
```

This trys stripping the preceding whitespace before checking if it is at an end
of input.

Answer (score 2):

In case the amount of "\n" is random, I would use this version (rather than adding an additional parser):

```
parseProperties :: Parser (String,String)
parseProperties = do
  skipMany newline -- optional newline(s)
  char '>' >> spaces >> char '<'
  propName <- many1 (noneOf ">")
  char '>'
  newline
  propValue <- many1 (noneOf "\n")
  skipMany newline  -- optional newline(s)
  return (propName,propValue)
```

I tried this version:

```
 parseTest (many1 parseProperties) "\n>  <CdId>\n1\n\n>  <Mol Weight>\n270.2369\n\n><Formula>\nC15H10O5\n\n>  <LOG_ER_RBA>\n-0.36\n\n>  <ACTIVITY>\n1\n\n"
```

And got:

```
[("CdId","1"),("Mol Weight","270.2369"),("Formula","C15H10O5"),("LOG_ER_RBA","-0.36"),     ("ACTIVITY","1")]
```